# mod_security / Atomicorp Basic WAF: URI in POST

Tags: php, apache, mod-security

I use `mod_security` with the WAF Basic Rules by Atomicorp.com on my Apache webserver. It prevents me from doing a POST of a form, containing an URI.

For example, if I POST `https://example.com/demo` via form, there a `403 Forbidden` error occures.

This is my Apache log file:

```
"/etc/httpd/conf/modsecurity.d/rules/tortix/modsec/50_plesk_basic_asl_rules.conf"] [line "207"] [id "340162"] [rev "294"] [msg "Protected by Atomicorp.com Basic Non-Realtime WAF Rules: URL detected as argument, possible RFI attempt detected"] [data "%TX:1,TX:1"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [hostname "*****.de"] [uri "/admin/"] [unique_id "*****"]
```

Can I just deactivate the rule with the ID `340162` or is there any other solution (maybe even without JavaScript)? I do not think that this rule is very important for me, because I am not a beginner programmer and does not have any `eval(file_get_contents($_GET['url']));` or something other of this sort in my code ;-)

Comment: You can disable the rules per application based on the following link: https://www.atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/Mod_security

Comment: @Phani: Yes, I have it disabled already for my application and it works fine. But my problem is, that it is a very important feature in my software to POST URIs. I just want to know, if I can pass this rule - and if yes how exactly - by masking URI in a simple way.

Comment: Then you may want to look at customizing rules section on the above link.

Answer (score 2):

In Plesk 12 you can go to `Tools & Settings` > `Web Application Firewall (ModSecurity)` and insert rule_id 340162 next to `Security rule IDs` (below `Switch off security rules`).